# My layout is not fitting in the frame layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Please help me fix my layout my Categories are hidden below the recent layout & they're barely showing. I've tried to add the ScrollView but it's showing the error " binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)" in this code. I've attached the snapshot to see the layout error. Sorry for my silly mistakes I am a newbie.

[See the category text & Image is barely visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McfaE.jpg)

fragment_home.xml

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">  
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best of the Month"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_bomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/bom"
        android:id="@+id/recent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Wallpapers"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_recentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/recent"
        android:id="@+id/cat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Categories"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_categories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>    
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

activity.main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"> 
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    </FrameLayout> 
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_below="@id/nestedScrollview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Home Fragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    db.collection("bestofthemonth").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
       val listBestOfTheMonth = arrayListOf<BomModel>()
        val data = value?.toObjects(BomModel::class.java)
        listBestOfTheMonth.addAll(data!!)

        binding.rcvBomLayout.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true)
        binding.rcvBomLayout.adapter = BomAdapter(requireContext(), listBestOfTheMonth)

    }
```

Comment: So it's a layout problem rather than a Firebase one, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes it's a layout issue sorry for adding firebase.

Answer (score 0):

With using `ScrollView`  try to update `android:layout_height="match_parent"` from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of `LinearLayout` that have `android:id="@+id/cat"`.

Comment: I tried this showing error "ScrollView can host only one direct child
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Comment: Oh, so for this please see this link: https://www.zidsworld.com/fix-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollview first with framelayout as child because scrollview can only have 1 direct child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        //other layout/views

    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Use NestedScrollView instead ScrollView if you want to include recyclerview inside scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        //other layout/views

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
```

Comment: I tried the NestedScrollView but it didn't work idk why? Any other thing I can try?

Comment: what do you mean not  work?

Comment: I don't know I've updated the code please look into it.